# Azure SQL Backup and Restore

Tags: sql, database, azure

I know Azure does automatic backup and restoring based off those automatic backups. I need to create a manual backup of a database. From reading online, I created a bacpac file using Export and saved to an Azure Blob ([how to here](http://suxstellino.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/backup-windows-azure-sql-database-with-sql-server-management-studio/)). The problem is when I go to 'Restore' using the Azure Portal, it only gives me the option to choose one of their automated backups.

On top of this, I would actually like to restore that database to another database (think restoring Production to Test). I cannot do this either.

I believe they used to have an Import + Export function when in the portal. Now it is Restore and Export, I'm wondering if they somehow took this capability away, I'm not sure.

I know I can create a new database from a .bacpac file, but this does not help me in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 0):

There is a copy command you can execute from the old portal.  Select a DB from the list and a copy toolbar item appears.